# Sending and receiving $_POST through curl

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to write a simplified middle-tier that forwards $_POST received from front end and returns response received from the server side.

Following is my php for sending $_POST:

```
<?php
$username= 'testuser';
$password = '123' ;
$fields = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
echo 'hello world' ; //checking
$url = 'url';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

And this is the php file that receives the curl and just echoes back $_POST(for checking if it is received correctly).

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"])) {
    echo $_POST["username"];}

if (isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
    echo $_POST["password"];}

?>
```

When i run this on my web server, I just get "Hello world" back. What do I need to change in order to get the response username/password back ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get them back"? You sent them into nirwana, since `'url'` certainly is not a valid url. but even _if_ you would use a valid url there, you would post those values to that url. Why should you received them _back_? This is a good example why it is not a good idea to skip error handling. Error handling would have revealed that your curl request fails due to that url you chose. Also a look into the error log file would show that.

Comment: Url will be url of my second php file  that i have posted. Normally I would receive things like database response to a particular combination of password and username worked or not. I just echoed username/password back here just to check if the receiving end is getting POST fields or not. Sorry for giving the wrong impression.

Comment: You need to read about what format `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` expects...

Answer (score 0):

It needs a query, not an array, like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Still getting just "hello world"

Answer (score 0):

I found this very useful tutorial to for sending standard $_POST requests and displaying their output: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Here's my program that echoes the $_POST fields forwarded to a another php file, php program that sends:

```
<?php
//mid1.php
$username= 'testuser';
$password = '123' ;
$url = 'https://xxxx/mid2.php';
$fields = array('username' => urlencode($username),'password' => urlencode($password));
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Here is the php program that receives POST and just echoes back:

```
<?php
//mid2.php

if (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"])) {
    echo $_POST["username"];}

if (isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
    echo $_POST["password"];}

?>
```